# Does Mac Phone Connector Increase Play Count?

Tags: phone-connector-mac

Updating the play count for a song in iTunes is important for Last.fm scrobbling.

Windows Phone 7 Connector for Mac is [meant to increase](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2010-10/26/windows-phone-7-connector-for-mac-os-x) the play count in iTunes when you sync your device.

On the music page in Phone Connector I have *Sync music From iTunes library* checked, but when I press the sync button the play count is never increased in iTunes. I have tried closing iTunes 10 and re-opening it.

How can I get the play count to increase?

Comment: One of my friends has this problem when syncing to Zune on his PC. I spent ages looking for a solution and I could find nothing that would solve it. I've seen loads of people asking about it for the PC so it seems like a fairly common problem. I think it's just one of those bugs that you're stuck with. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may have been a bug in an earlier version of the software.

The app is now simply called **Windows Phone** and is [available through the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/windows-phone/id415571499?mt=12).

I played a track on both the Lumia 800 (WP7) and Lumia 920 (WP8) and synced back with my iTunes library (Mac OS 10.8.4, iTunes 11.0.4) and the play count increased by 1 in both cases, as expected.